# Make videos not downloadable - yet play them to users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, video, rubygems, html5-video

We are considering using [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5) to display videos to users.  But we do not want users to view the html source and the grab the url of the video and then download that video through their browser.  Is there a way to hide the url or prevent downloads of files using rails or another method (yet still be able to play the videos to users through a player)?

Answer (score 1):

You can not ever prevent your users from downloading the video, after all it **has** to be downloaded in order to display it to the user.

You can only make it more difficult for the user.

Answer (score 0):

I believe JWPlayer supports streaming, if you set up a stream server, the user won't be able to just download the video.

EDIT: the user won't be able to just download the file as a download link, it'll be more difficult though.